# Blackberry 10 stacktrace for Android runtime (like `adb logcat`)

Tags: android, blackberry-10, android-logcat

I am using the BB10 porting tools to turn my Android APK into a BB10 BAR.

On **BB10**, is there a **tool** that provides **similar functionality** to the Android **`adb logcat`** command?

So I can see my log statements, and stack traces on crash.

---

### Workaround

Currently, the best replacement I have is that Crashlytics still works on the BB10 port and provides a stack trace.

Logging works with Flurry, at a push, but the turnaround time is terrible as this is really not what this is for.